# How would one create a function as a result of a higher order function?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am going through the definition of a higher order function. Based on the definition, a higher order function can take value or function and create a function or value as output. I am reading F# and Erlang book and so far I did not find one where a function creates a function as a result or I have seen it bud it did not come out to me as resultant function. I understood a function taking function as an input (like Action or Func<> in C#) Here is a sample code based on [wikibook on F#](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Higher_Order_Functions)

```
open System

let square x = x * x    

let cube x = x * x * x

let sign x =
    if x > 0 then "positive"
    else if x < 0 then "negative"
    else "zero"

let passFive f = (f 5)
```

In this example, is the passFile a high order function which in turn creating a function as an output? If it is, not could someone show me a simple example where function generates a function as a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple example is just a curried function.

Take

```
let multiply (a : int) (b : int) : int = a * b
```

for example. 
Just writing it's signature you have something like

```
int -> int -> int
```

which is really

```
int -> (int -> int)
```

So this **is** a function that takes one integer (`a`) and returns another function:

```
multiply 5 == fun b -> 5 * b
```

As you see higher-order functions are all around in functional programming / F# when you use curried functions.

Your example on the other side can be rewritten as:

```
let passFive (f : int -> 'b) : 'b = f 5
```

So this is a higher-order function in the sense that it takes an function (`f`) but it does not return one - as the name suggests it passes a `5` into every function you call it with (another common name might be *apply* 5).

Answer (score 2):

Another example would be the composition operators `(>>)` and `(<<)`.  These take two functions and compose them into a single function.  For example:

```
let twoNPlusOne = (*) 2 >> (+) 1
```

The type of the operator is `('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'c)`; in this case, all type variables are `int` as the operands are both `int -> int` and so is the result.

Comment: yep +1 (there are lots's of those) - of course the operator itself is a curried function `(>>) : ('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c)` :D